# GetTokenInformation fails (error 998) on windows server 2003 but works on 2008

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have a problem when calling GetTokenInformation, 
for some reason it fails on windows server 2003 32bit but succeeds on server 2008 64bit.

```
    PTOKEN_USER pSIDTokenUser = NULL;
    DWORD       dwReturnLength;   

    if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, NULL, 0, &dwReturnLength) && GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
           //handle error
    }

    pSIDTokenUser = (PTOKEN_USER)new BYTE[dwReturnLength];
    memset(pSIDTokenUser, 0, dwReturnLength); 


    if (!pSIDTokenUser)
           //handle error

    if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, pSIDTokenUser, dwReturnLength, NULL))
           //handle error
```

the second call to GetTokenInformation on windows 2003 always return 0 with the error 998 ("Invalid access to memory location").
I assume it has something to do with the pSIDTokenUser size/alignment (I use the default)  etc, but could not find the reason.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final parameter, `ReturnLength` is not optional, according to the function annotations. Don't pass NULL in the second call. You appear to be getting away with it on Windows 2008.

Comment: Working like a charm, thanks a lot! its a little subtle i guess especially since its working on 2008.